# How to attach VPC and subnet in request_spot_instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, boto3, amazon-vpc

We have multiple subnet and VPC. How do i define specific subnet and VPC during request_spot_instances?

following is my code:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.request_spot_instances(
    DryRun=False,
    ClientToken=''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=10)),
    InstanceCount=1,
    Type='one-time',
    LaunchSpecification={
        'ImageId': 'ami-db710fa3',
        'KeyName': 'my_key',
        'InstanceType': 'm4.4xlarge',
        'Placement': {
            'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-2a',
        },
        'BlockDeviceMappings': [
            {
                'Ebs': {
                    # 'SnapshotId': 'snap-f70deff0',
                    'VolumeSize': 100,
                    'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                    'VolumeType': 'gp2',
                    'Iops': 300,
                    'Encrypted': False
                },
            },
        ],

        'EbsOptimized': True,
        'Monitoring': {
            'Enabled': True
        },
        'SecurityGroupIds': ['sg-1231231' ],
        'NetworkInterfaces': [
            {
                'DeviceIndex': 123,
                'SubnetId': 'Subnet-df123123'
            },
        ],

    }
)
```

However, above code is throwing errors,

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the RequestSpotInstances
>   operation: Network interfaces and an instance-level security groups
>   may not be specified on the same request

any help is appreciated  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all: *Network interfaces and an instance-level security groups may not be specified on the same request*

This is because `NetworkInterfaces` has a sub-parameter called `Groups` where you specify the Security Group. This is required because multiple network interfaces can be specified, with different security groups for each.

If `NetworkInterfaces` is *not* specified, you can use `SecurityGroupIds` (at the same level as `NetworkInterfaces`) and the groups will be applied to the default network interface created with the instance.

So, if you don't actually need `'DeviceIndex': 123`, just delete the whole `NetworkInterfaces` bit and you should be fine.